# How to view a previous screen in an application

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent, cardlayout

My application contains many screens. I want to view the same screen previously loaded. If I already entered some data into that screen, the same data should also be displayed. Please advise me how to handle this case.

Comment: what have you tried? also it would help if you can post some relevant part of your code.

Comment: Define "screens" are these `Components` of some kind or actual windows?

Answer (score 4):

> ..screen previously loaded

- Put each group of components of a screen into a `JPanel`
- Give a `JFrame` a `CardLayout` and add each screen to it.

Then flipping backwards or forwards through each screen is simple.